# How can I use Twitch API in rails with the gem Cathodic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

so I have partnered a livestreamer & I would like to display dynamic information whether he is online or offline as well as the status. I don't quite understand the process I would take to place this information on my homepage with the gem Cathodic which contacts the Twitch API & makes it easier to use I guess.

Here is the gem information: https://github.com/kustom666/cathodic

Let me know if you are not understanding what I am asking & I will go more into detail.